# Chrome Extension: iframe in Background.html causing background script tun run 2x

Tags: google-chrome, background

I am developing a Chrome Extension which has a background.js and *.html.

In this *.html there is an iframe implemented which causes the script of background.js to run 2x (every single command is doubled).

In the extension details there is this line:

Check view (translated from German "Ansichten prüfen"): background.html (iFrame) background.html

Is there any way to prevent this double code running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <iframe id = "iframe" src = "" width = "545" height = "581" scrolling = "yes" frameborder = "0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

The problem was that the src of the iframe was set to "#". The code above works just fine now.